# Iterating data from firebase into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
ArrayList<Site> siteList = new ArrayList<>();

String UID = user.getUid();

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Users").child(UID);
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/Users").child(UID);
```

Getting no. of sites

```
database.child("Site No").get().addOnSuccessListener(dataSnapshot -> site_no = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()));
```

Trying to iterate

```
for(int i = 1; i<site_no; i++){
    database.child("Sites").orderByChild("Site "+ i).get().addOnSuccessListener(dataSnapshot -> {
        Site site = dataSnapshot.getValue(Site.class);
        storage.child("Site " + i).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
            assert site != null;
            site.setSiteImage(uri);
            siteList.add(site);
            System.out.println(siteList);
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Database Image]

I want the data to be added into siteList arraylist, as I want to display it in a recycler view.

Comment: what isn't working ? you have an `addOnSuccessListener`, do you have any failure listeners ? any logs or anything to show what's happening ?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: After some debugging I found out that the DatabaseReference and StorageReference are throwing NullPointerException, don't know why.

Comment: Try changing the paths for your database references.